# Facebook Insights - Event Data Missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I'm having a problem with the events I'm sending to Facebook Insights. I've got about 15 custom events I'm sending, and they all carry a data object that is pretty consistent between all the events. 10 of the events show up with the data object working fine (see graphic User Logged In/Out events), and for the rest, I'm getting "No data is available for the current selection." (see graphic Story Played/Selected events).

I believe with one event I shortened the Event Type, and the data started displaying properly. I tried this with other events, and that didn't fix the problem. Has anyone had this sort of problem before, and could you please comment about your solution?

I'm using Adobe AIR for mobile, running on Android, using the Milkman Games GoViral ANE. Another important factor here is that I'm sending these exact same events to a different analytics service - Mixpanel. All the events look correct on Mixpanel, so I'm pretty sure I'm sending them out properly. My assumption at the moment is that Facebook doesn't like something specific about some of my events.

**I'm interested in any comments about this general kind of issue, regardless of platform or implementation**, to see if I can figure out what's going wrong. I know my app setup is not so common, so for the sake of this question I'd like to ignore that for the time being.

Thanks in advance for any help you might provide.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. It turns out Facebook Insights events have a limit of 10 properties per event. Once I reduced the data being sent, the other events started tracking properly.